# Use parent directory base name for making a new directories in a for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv, for, cd-command

I am attempting to use a for loop to move files (e.g. .txt) into a new directory, where the original directory name as part of the name, but add an extra "with-new-files" onto the name so I know that the directory is new and what it contains.

Since I have ~10 directories with .txt files in the parent directory, I'd ideally like to use a for loop rather than having to manually create new directories and move the files.

For example, I have something similar to the following:

```
1_SpecialDirectoryNameA
    - fileA1.txt
    - fileA2.txt
    - unrelated_directory_A

2_SpecialDirectoryNameB
    - fileB1.txt
    - fileB2.txt
    - unrelated_directory_B
```

What I want:

```
1_SpecialDirectoryNameA
    - unrelated_directory_A

2_SpecialDirectoryNameB
    - unrelated_directory_B

New-directories-with-files
    - 1_SpecialDirectoryNameA_with_new_files
         - fileA1.txt
         - fileA2.txt
    - 2_SpecialDirectoryNameB_with_new_files
        - fileB1.txt
        - fileB2.txt
```

I've tried the following code, but I'm stuck at the mkdir step, where I get these messages:
mkdir: 1_SpecialDirectoryNameA: No such file or directory
mkdir: 2_SpecialDirectoryNameB: No such file or directory

```
mkdir New-directories-with-files

for dir in */   
do
    cd $dir
    mkdir "${dir}_with_new_files"
    mv *.txt "${dir}_with_new_files"
    mv "${dir}_with_new_files" ../New-directories-with-files/
    cd ../
done
```

So far, the only thing I've gotten to work successfully is:

```
for dir in */   
do
    cd $dir
    mkdir newfolder_files
    cd ../
done
```

Using this code I can successfully get the .txt files moved into the new "newfolder_files" directory, but then I would have to manually change the names to 1_newfolder_files before moving all of them  new directory together.

I'm just not sure how to implement adding parent directory name with the ${dir} bit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see it is that with the way you match directory names including the trailing slash, so `$dir` will contain `1_SpecialDirectoryNameA/` and `mkdir ${dir}_with_new_files` will resolve to `mkdir 1_SpecialDirectoryNameA/_with_new_files` and `mkdir` without the `-p` flag will not create parent folders, so thats where the error comes from.

One way to avoid this is to use `${dir%/}_with_new_files` instead this is a shell parameter extension, similar to the one used int [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20796575)

An other problem I see is that the `for dir in */` part of your script will also match your newly created directory, so it may be a good idea to create it somewhere safe (such as the parent folder)

So a possible modified version of your script would be

```
mkdir ../New-directories-with-files

for dir in */
do
    cd $dir
    mkdir "${dir%/}_with_new_files"
    mv *.txt "${dir%/}_with_new_files"
    mv "${dir%/}_with_new_files" ../../New-directories-with-files/
    cd ../
done

mv ../New-directories-with-files .
```

Answer (score 0):

Michelle, your `for` loop is populating `dir` with the directory's names *including trailing slashes*. You can trim them on the fly by replacing `${dir}` with `${dir%%/}`; the `%%` indicates you want to exclude the pattern that follows from the end of the variable. (Note that you're not actually changing the variable content itself, only its substitution in that point of the code.)

There's another issue with your script: your `for` loop will also iterate over the new directory you created in the first line ("New-directories-with-files"). Perhaps instead of `for dir in */` you could use `for dir in *_*/`, assuming your directories' names follow the pattern in your example. Another option would be placing the "New-directories-with-files" in the parent directory.